# static_assert the signedness of wide character literals?

Tags: c, static-assert

**I would like to [`static_assert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/error/static_assert) that the signedness of wide character literals (`L'x'`) matches that of `wchar_t`**.

The definition of `wchar_t` is my own. (I am implementing a C standard library.) I would like to fail early, fail loud if the compiler used by a user has a different idea about wide character signedness than what is configured in the library.

Asserting a matching **size** of the types is easy:

```
static_assert( sizeof( wchar_t ) == sizeof( L'x' ), "size matches" );
```

For the builtin type `char`, testing the signedness is easy. Assuming there is a `_CHAR_IS_SIGNED` defined to either 0 or 1 somewhere,

```
static_assert( ( (char)-1 < 0 ) == _CHAR_IS_SIGNED, "char is signed" );
```

does the trick.

But `wchar_t` is *not* a builtin type...

Is there a way to make this (static) assertion in "pure" C99 or C11, i.e. without relying on a specific compiler's extensions?

---

**Clarification:**

I "am" the library. I have to `typedef` some integer type to `wchar_t`.

The compiler -- not me -- defines wide character literals to some type. This type is *not* assigned a name by the compiler, but ideally should be identical to whatever I am using for `wchar_t`, including signedness (which, AFAICT, is not specified by the standard).

I would like to assert / test the identity of these types in some way. The `(type)-1 < 0` check shown for `char` above does not work, *because I cannot name "the type the compiler uses for literals"*.

Comment: Off the top of my head: casting `-1` to the required type?

Comment: @LPs: The question is basically, how do I cast `-1` to `typeof( L'x' )` without such a thing as `typeof()`?

Comment: `_CHAR_IS_SIGNED` is no standard macro. A better approach would be to enforce `signed` or `unsigned` `wchar_t`. Anyway, wide character support in the C standard is somewhat broken anyway. And most modern systems use UTF-8.

Comment: For any type and any signedness, why can't you just do `static_assert((type)-1 < 0, "type is signed" );`. This should be portable regardless of integer sizes and regardless of signedness format.

Comment: @Olaf: I cannot enforce, from within a standard library, what the **compiler** uses for its literals. That's the very problem I am trying to solve here.

Comment: @Lundin: If I *could* specify "the type the compiler uses for wide character literals" in some way, I wouldn't have a problem. Note that `wchar_t` is mine (the library) to define, but should match the type the compiler uses for literals (which is, unfortunately, **unnamed**).

Comment: Then want you a solution that does not use `sizeof` nor `typeof`?

Comment: It is not unnamed. The compiler uses `wchar_t` for literals... Try for example `puts(_Generic(L' ', wchar_t: "wchar_t"));`.

Comment: @LPs: `sizeof()` does not tell me about signedness, `typeof()` doesn't exist. ;-)

Comment: Are there any boundaries how you define your own type: Is it always unsigned? What is the `sizeof` of it compared to `int`?

Comment: @DevSolar: You mean **a** C library you want to use for various projects or **the** C standard library (there is only one)? For the latter semantics are well defined and you should not enforce a particular signed-ness. For your own library (which I assumed you mean) you should just use appropriate declarations for the arguments (e.g. `(un)signed wchar_t`).

Comment: @Olaf: I am indeed implementing **the C standard library**. And no, the signedness of `wchar_t` / wide character literals is, as far as I could tell, not specified. I'd like to make sure that my library agrees with whatever the compiler uses.

Comment: @DevSolar: I did not write the signed-ness is defined, but the semantics, i.e. how to handle them. Not sure about wchar_t, but for e.g. `memset`, the argument is used as `unsigned char`, independent which signed-ness `char` actually has (I'm aware, the argument is actually a `char` passed as an `int`). So they enforce `unsigned char` semantics, although the original `char` could be either.

Comment: @Olaf: ...which is because only `unsigned char` is guaranteed to not have any trap representation, while `char` isn't (although that is taking it to the really fine print). What are you trying to say here? What I am trying to avoid here are spurious signed / unsigned mismatch warnings resulting from different types used by the compiler and the library functions.

Comment: @Lundin: That as an answer would get the checkmark (as you ninja'd HolyBlackCat by a comfortable margin). I'd forgotten about `_Generic`...

Comment: `((L'\0' - L'\1') < L'\0')` is probably the test you are looking for.

Comment: C11 explicitly says wide characters can be signed or unsigned and their minimum width is 8 bits.

Comment: `static_assert( ((wchar_t)-1 < 0) == (-L'\1' < 0)), "same sign-ness" );` may be sufficient.

Comment: @n.m. promoted to `int` probably. My `wchar_t` is `int`, so I cannot test.

Comment: @chux It may work incorrectly: `std::cout << (((signed char)-1 < 0) == (-(unsigned char)1 < 0));` prints 1.

Comment: OTOH `-L'\1'` --> `(int)` Hmmmm.

Comment: My other idea was to make a biig constant and see if it is negative. Too bad these are implementation defined as well.

Comment: @n.m. It may work incorrectly too: `std::cout << (((unsigned char)0 - (unsigned char)1) < (unsigned char)0);` prints 1.

Comment: @Antti yes, my bad

Comment: @DevSolar The posted answer is fine, no need to post a second one. I've got enough rep not to care, long as the problem is solved :) I did consider what alternatives there might be without C11 though, but couldn't find any. Main problem is you can't do any form of arithmetic on the `L' '` literal without changing its type. For example the expression `L'\0' - L'\1'` could possibly have solved the problem, but then integer promotion kicks in and ruins it.

Comment: @Lundin: That's probably why I found this such a hard nut to crack. I started this project *ages* ago (2002, to be exact), and passed maintenance to someone else in 2012 without even *knowing* of C11. I only just returned to the project, and C11 simply hasn't "sunk in" for me yet as I don't "do" plain C anywhere else. `_Generic` just didn't pop up in my mind as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need to check if compiler uses signed or unsigned type for wide char literals.

You can simply test if a type of wide char literals matches your typedef:

```
static_assert(_Generic(L'.', wchar_t : 1, default : 0), "blahblah");
```

---

But if you really want to get the type signedness, use something like this:

```
static_assert(_Generic(L'.', char : ((char)-1 < 0), signed char : 1, short : 1, int : 1, long : 1, long long : 1, default : 0) == _WIDE_CHAR_IS_SIGNED, "blahblah");
```

And (as @chux suggested) here is a safer version which forces a compilation error if wide characters type doesn't match any of the standard ones.

```
#define T(x) signed x : 1, unsigned x : 0 // Makes the code more readable
static_assert(_Generic(L'.', char : ((char)-1 < 0), T(char), T(short), T(int), T(long), T(long long)) == _WIDE_CHAR_IS_SIGNED, "blahblah");
#undef T
```

Comment: This is neat, but I don't believe it works with C99?

Comment: @user694733 Yes, it requires C11, but OP said that C11 is ok for him.

Comment: *sigh* -- Back when I started this project, C99 was the "current" standard. C11 gave me many useful tools, but also many more things to implement before I'd be done. ;-) Reluctant to checkmark this, as @Lundin commented first about `_Generic` (which I had totally forgotten about). If he doesn't put it into an answer, you'll get the "green hook" in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Ah heck, here goes. Ty.

Comment: Re:  type signed-ness:  This make a reasonable assumption that the candidate signed type are the enumeration ones: `char`, `signed char`, `int`, ... but unnecessarily assumes anything else if unsigned.  Better to enumerate candidate unsigned types too and leave the default off.  Then should a rare machine not match the list, the compile will fail, rather than present the wrong answer.

Comment: The first `static_assert()` works if `wchar_t` and `L'.'` are the same type - which is good.  But it may be sufficient for OP that they are of the equivalent range like `unsigned` and `unsigned long` could be.  IAC for OP's goal, finding _the_ matching type, rather than an equivalent is better.

Comment: @chux About type signedness: Good point, added that. | About types with same range: I agree, IMO it's better for OP to find the exact type. Also, it's harder to compare range anyway.